# How to freeze a layer's weights for some number of iterations?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to train two MLP's jointly, each one to predict a different real-valued variable. I want to minimize a loss over these two outputs, but I want to fix one of them for some number of "warm-up" iterations.

I'm new to tensorflow, but basically I'm looking for the equivalent of something like this in Pytorch:

```
def loss(self, *args, **kwargs) -> torch.Tensor:
        # Extract data
        data, target, probability = args

        # Iterate through each model and sum nll
        nll = []
        for index in range(self.num_models):
            # Extract mean and variance from prediction
            if self._current_it < self.warm_start_it:
                predictive_mean = self.mean[index](data)
                with torch.no_grad():
                    predictive_variance = softplus(self.variance[index](data))
            else:
                with torch.no_grad():
                    predictive_mean = self.mean[index](data)
                predictive_variance = softplus(self.variance[index](data))

            # Calculate the loss
            nll.append(self.calculate_nll(target, predictive_mean, predictive_variance))

        mean_nll = torch.stack(nll).mean()

        # Update current iteration
        if self.training:
            self._current_it += 1

        return mean_nll
```

I'm thinking I can do something similar inside my model's `call()` function, i.e.:

```
    def call(self, step, inputs, training=None, mask=None):

        if step < self.warmup:
            with tf.GradientTape() as t:
                mean_predictions = self.mean(inputs)
            var_predictions = self.variance(inputs)
        else:
            mean_predictions = self.mean(inputs)
            with tf.GradientTape() as t:
                var_predictions = self.variance(inputs)
        return mean_predictions, var_predictions
```

Is this the correct way of getting the above Pytorch equivalent?

Comment: Sounds like `tf.stop_gradient` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

In a main loop,

```
mlp = UncertaintyMLP(805, 1)
    loss_fn = GaussianNLL()
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
    epochs = 1000
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for step, (x_batch, y_batch) in enumerate(train_dataset):

            if epoch > mlp.warmup:
                for layer in mlp.mean.layers:
                    layer.trainable = False
                for layer in mlp.variance.layers:
                    layer.trainable = True
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                output = mlp(step, x_batch)
                loss = loss_fn(y_batch, output)
            grads = tape.gradient(loss, mlp.trainable_weights)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, mlp.trainable_weights))
```

and in the model class:

```
def call(self, step, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
    mean_predictions = self.mean(inputs)
    var_predictions = tf.math.softplus(self.variance(inputs)
    return mean_predictions, var_predictions
```

However I'm still curious to see what, if any, would be Tensorflow's equivalent of Pytorch's `torch.no_grad()`.

Comment: Did you find the equivalent to `torch.no_grad()`? Really need to find out.

Comment: your best bet is the `trainable` attribute of keras layers. you can set it to what you want, as above.